# why different output from zabbix_get and zabbix_agentd command?

Tags: postgresql, docker, zabbix

I am trying to monitor psql container through zabbix. My zabbix-server is not allowed to gather data. I am getting different output for zabbix_get and zabbix_agentd command.
output of zabbix_agentd is-

> [root@ip-]# zabbix_agentd -t
>   psql.running[/usr/local/bin,/usr/local/etc]
>   psql.running[/usr/local/bin,/usr/local/etc]   [t|1]

output from zabbix_get is as-

> [root@ip]# zabbix_get -s127.0.0.1 -p10050 -k
>   psql.running[/usr/local/bin,/usr/local/etc]
>   psql: could not connect to
>   server: Permission denied
>           Is the server running on host "10.20.39.11" and accepting
>           TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Answer (score 1):

When you run zabbix_agentd, you run it as the root user, and your environment is different.

When you run zabbix_get, it connects to a running agent daemon. This daemon runs as the 'zabbix' user and has different environment variables.

In this case, you should test your userparameter command as the 'zabbix' user.

Comment: I added `AllowRoot=1` parameter in my zabbix_agentd.conf file. So it wont be an issue.